# Generate Query String with jQuery from simple fields?

Tags: jquery

I've got some REALLY simple fields, like a checkbox for yes/no's and some text inputs for width/height etc.

I'd like to have users check a box for a feature and define their sizes, so if they check `<input type="checkbox" id="header" name="header" value="true" />` then I want to add `&show_header=true` to the query string.

I've got a very [basic fiddle set up](http://jsfiddle.net/demchak_alex/AYQyB/2/), but I can't seem to get it to work properly. Like, if you check the box, then fill in the value, but uncheck the box, it starts to repeat things and I end up with `&show_header=true&show_header=true&show_header=true&show_header=true&show_header=true`

Comment: just give the input the name `show_header` and use `serialize()`... http://api.jquery.com/serialize

Comment: Thanks for the link - I was unaware of that! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply use [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method:

```
function displayVals() {
    $("code").html(function(i, val) {
        var query = $("input").serialize();
        return "http://...?method=review_box&amp;" + query;
    });
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/AYQyB/4/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to reinvent [jQuery's .serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function.

```
<form>
    <div><input type="text" name="a" value="1" id="a" /></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="b" value="2" id="b" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" name="c" value="3" id="c" /></div>
    <div>
        <textarea name="d" rows="8" cols="40">4</textarea>
    </div>
    <div><select name="e">
        <option value="5" selected="selected">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
    </select></div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="f" value="8" id="f" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="g" value="Submit" id="g" />
    </div>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    alert($(this).serialize());
    return false;
});
```

Produces:

```
a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4&e=5
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe so?

```
<input class="my-vars" type="checkbox" name="rbshowheader" id="rbshowheader" value="true" />
<input class="my-vars" type="text" name="rbwidth" id="rbwidth_id" value="" />
<pre><code>http://yoursite.whirlocal.com?method=review_box</code><span id="query"></span></pre>
```

and JavaScript

```
$(function() {
  $('.my-vars').change( function() {
     var sQuery = $('.my-vars').serialize();
     $('#query').html('&'+sQuery);
   });
});
```